# Is it possible to bind functions to window using "var" from inside a function?

Tags: javascript, scope, this

Preface: I'm a language researcher trying to accomodate a very specific use case of JavaScript. I am aware of "best practices" regarding scoping and usage of window, etc.

In scenario A below, the function *bam* is added to the global scope, available on the window object. In scenario B, the *wrapperFn* is executed in the global scope, but *bam* is not added to the global window object. In scenario C, it's clear that *this* refers to window.

Is there any way to add items to window from within functions using the "var .." declaration syntax (e.g **not** window.foo = func...)? What's the difference between eval'ing a global script compared to executing a function in the window context?

Scenario A:

```
<html>
<script>     
  var bam = function () {}
  window.bam();  //runs bam 
</script>
</html>
```

Scenario B:

```
<html>
<script>     
  var wrapperFn = function(){
    var bam = function(){};
  };

  wrapperFn.apply(window);  //Executed in window context
  window.bam()  //bam is undefined
</script>
</html>
```

Scenario C:

```
<html>
<script>  
  var wrapperFn = function(){
    this.bam = function(){};
    console.log(this === window);  //true
  };

  wrapperFn.apply(window);
  window.bam() //runs bam
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: If you'd describe this "very specific use case", perhaps somebody can provide an explicit suggestion.

Comment: @Pointy, I'm researching javascript instrumentation (e.g. https://github.com/adobe-research/fondue) and cannot modify original sources on pages. Instead, I need to wrap some of the globally executed javascript in functions and later invoke them as if they were ran globally.

Comment: @RayonDabre -- this is what i feared, are there any crazy hacks that might make this work?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't downvote and it's not a bad question.  That explanation in the comment is helpful. No, you can't force the runtime to make local variables be global without your own modifications internally (to the runtime). Local variables are local, and that's that. Things like browser debuggers *do* have special access to runtime internals, of course.

Comment: @y3sh, Why cant you use `window.` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre I _could_ but don't want to. I'm augmenting source code that others wrote and don't want to modify their code. The use-case is to wrap statements executed in the global scope for tracing and analytics. But I may only be able to wrap the function body, not the "var" part.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one way to add anything to `window` using the declarative `var` keyword and that is with the frowned upon `with` keyword.

```
with (window) {
  var bam = console.log.bind(console)
}
```

This will allow you to run `window.bam('test')` (at least in Chrome).

To learn more about the `with` keyword, checkout the MDN page for it.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

> JavaScript looks up an unqualified name by searching a scope chain associated with the execution context of the script or function containing that unqualified name. The 'with' statement adds the given object to the head of this scope chain during the evaluation of its statement body. If an unqualified name used in the body matches a property in the scope chain, then the name is bound to the property and the object containing the property. Otherwise a ReferenceError is thrown.

**Extra**
The reason your `bam` in B is `undefined` is because the scope in the "block" is the defined function `wrapperFn`. That doesn't mean that `wrapperFn.bam` is defined but rather `bam` is only available to any other code available in the `wrapperFn` block.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that this will not work if you place the _with_ block inside a function?

Comment: Correct, the execution scope changes so declarations are non-visible  to the outside scope(s)

Comment: Just ran some tests, the only way to use `with` is outside of a function–  execute the `with` in the same scope of the `expression`

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly create properties of the global context (`window`):

```
function g() {
  window.someFunction = function() {
    console.log("hi!");
  };
}

g();
someFunction(); // "hi!"
```

Variables declared with `var` inside functions are explicitly *not* global, but nothing prevents you making a copy of a value into a global property.

```
function g() {
  var someFunction = function() {
    console.log("hi!");
  };
  window.someFunction = someFunction;
}
```

Without such an explicit assignment, local variables are not global and cannot be made so.

Comment: No, you didn't use var. I'll clarify this.

Comment: This answer does not provide anything new that was not already stated in the question or comments on the question.

Comment: @y3sh the direct answer to your question is **no**.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `var` and it attach to window. However, it's not good practice to having a dirty window object. It's better to create namespaces.

```
  function x() {
         theVar = true ; // global, attached to window 
  }
```

Comment: Yes, but OP doesn't tell it

Comment: Agreed; I was just making that note for future Stackoverflow visitors :)

Comment: does this happen regardless of function context?

Comment: @y3sh a reference to an undefined symbol on the left side of an assignment will cause a global variable to be created when the code is not running in "strict" mode. In "strict" mode, the code in this answer would produce an error.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, Op wants it **using “var”**